# How to be sure the GTA V "play disk" isn't installed?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

After reading all the problems caused by installing both disks on the Xbox360, I was wondering if I did the installation process as suggested.
After installing the first disk I was asked to insert the second one. I'm not sure if there was an option to skip this stage and I'm not quite sure if, during this stage, the second disk was actually installed or that was just a required step to start the game from disk. As far as I remember, I was never asked to install the second disk.

I was wondering about this cause I noticed the "popup" effect during the [beach scene](http://youtu.be/v0gPB0gdoOM?t=15s)

How can I tell if I mistakenly installed the "play disk" too?

Comment: Rockstar Games has just issued a fix : [Xbox 360 Freeze GTA V "Play Disc" issue](http://www.gamepur.com/news/12096-xbox-360-freezes-while-installing-gta-v-play-disc-data-rockstar-issues-fix.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing the "Play Disk" in the way being discussed would be an additional second step, which would be done from the Xbox 360 Dashboard (by looking at the game under "My Games" and selecting "Install Disk"). The splash screen it shows which doing this will be an Xbox 360 one, with a progress bar, rather than the GTA one.

If you think you may have done this, you can delete the game content in it's entirety through "Storage Management" in the settings. This would mean re-installing the first disk again.

However, some small visual flaws will be noticeable in any game. It's unlikely that you accidentally installed the second disk.

Comment: Will I lose my saved game if I do that?

Comment: @EricGagnon what does the storage management on the xbox say when you look at the GTA5 folder?

Comment: Nevermind actually, the saved files are separate from the game install files. I just deleted the Disc 2 content (around 8GB) and that did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You did everything right. It was a required step to finalize the installation.

I did the same and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to only delete the content from disk 2. I installed disk 2 in hope of GTA Online connecting better. Nothing was better and today I went into the storage settings from the dashboard and found an option " All Devices ". Clicked " Games and Apps " and was able to find everything that was stored under the name of GTAV. This could be a way for you if you are unsure. Though I can ensure you that installing the game like you described do not install the second disk.